# Cannot debug unit tests in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

This question is *very* similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024000/visual-studio-2012-suddenly-cannot-debug-tests), but I'm experiencing it in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.  I am running my tests locally (there is no remote test controller).

I recently started working on a client's .NET 4.0 project.  It has a suite of Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework unit tests.  When I launch the unit tests, IIS Express automatically starts.  I can *run* the unit tests dozens of times without any issues to see whether they pass or fail.  However, when I attempt to *debug* the unit tests (by right-clicking on a test in Test View and clicking `Debug Selection`), it almost always fails with the following error message:

> Error 3/19/2014 2:42:44 PM  Failed to queue test run 'ThoughtProcess@HOSTNAME 2014-03-19-14:42:40':  Process with an Id of [12345] is not running.

I say "almost" because every 20 or so clean starts of VS, it will successfully attach the debugger.  But I haven't been able to consistently reproduce this behavior.

I tried the suggestions from the Visual Studio 2012 post, but those didn't work in my situation.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of [this xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/979/), I did find a solution to this issue by installing ReSharper and using its test runner instead of the built-in Visual Studio test runner.

The ReSharper runner consistently and repeatably lets me run and debug unit tests without any issues.  I'm still not sure that I understand the underlying cause of why the VS runner can't debug, but hopefully this will save someone else future frustration.