# How can I pass values to xUnit tests that accept a nullable decimal?

Tags: c#, xunit

One of my unit tests has this signature:

```
public void FooWithFilter(string fooId, decimal? amount)
```

When I test it with null, it works:

```
[InlineData("123", null)]
```

But if I use an actual value, such as:

```
[InlineData("123", 610)]
```

I get an error:

```
System.ArgumentException Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be 
converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]'.
```

I tried using `610M` as the attribute value, but that's not allowed as an attribute value:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, type of expression
or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.
```

Is there a way to use a nullable decimal here?

Comment: `but that's not allowed as an attribute value` <= could you include in your question the compiler error message?

Comment: @Igor I get `[CS0182] An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`

Comment: Try: `[InlineData("123", (double?) 610.0)]` so it is a nullable type of int.

Comment: Attributes can only contain "primitive types".  Unfortunately, `Decimal` isn't a primitive type.

Comment: There are strict limitations to attribute initialization data, the values must be stored in the assembly meta data and only simple types are supported.  So right, no support for decimal, the CLR knows little about it.  You'll have to wing it with double or a string.  Why a unit test requires an attribute to invoke a method is not obvious.

Comment: I guess you could accept a string and then parse it to decimal inside the attribute at runtime.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm pretty sure neither one is primitive.

Comment: You're looking at either parsing from a string or switching from using `InlineData` to `ClassData` or `MemberData`

Comment: I went with a string, and used `Convert.ToDecimal()` when the string wasn't null. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @BobHorn As Jonathon Chase suggests, I think the right way to accomplish this is to use `ClassData`. That should allow you to use any data types you like: http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can't use a `decimal` here because `decimal` is not one of the types that's allowed in attribute parameter values.

However, xUnit provides a more flexible way to pass parameter values to test methods, using `ClassData`:

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(FooDataGenerator))]
public void FooWithFilter(string fooId, decimal? amount)
```

To use this, you simply need to define a class that extends `IEnumerable<object[]>` and produces the input values you want:

```
public class FooDataGenerator : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    private readonly List<object[]> _data = new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[] {"123", null},
        new object[] {"123", 610M}
    };

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator() => _data.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Some further references on the various ways of passing values to xUnit tests:
[Creating Parameterised tests in xUnit](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/)
[xUnit Theory: Working With InlineData, MemberData, ClassData](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/)

Comment: Thank you. I think it's worth noting this link as well: http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/

Comment: @BobHorn Added. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In addition to JLRishe's answer, I would suggest to inherit from `TheoryData` or its generic counterparty `TheoryData<>` so we get strongly typed test data and cleaner code. I find the documentation somehow thin in that respect.

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(FooDataGenerator))]
public void FooWithFilter(string fooId, decimal? expected)
{
    // Arrange // Act // Assert
}

public class FooDataGenerator : TheoryData<string, decimal?>
{
    public FooDataGenerator()
    {
        this.Add("987", null);
        this.Add("123", 610m);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A simple work arround for this problem is set the parameters double? and cast them to decimal? like so

```
[Theory]
        [InlineData(1200, 1150, 50, 100)]
        [InlineData(1200.50, 1200.50, 0, 0)]
        [InlineData(1250.50, 1150, 0, 100.50)]
        [InlineData(1150, 1150, null, null)]
        [InlineData(0, null, null, null)]
        [InlineData(-50, null, 50, null)]
        [InlineData(50, null, null, 50)]

        public void SubTotal(double valorEsperado, double? valorTotal, double? valorFrete, double? valorDesconto) =>
            Assert.Equal((decimal)valorEsperado, PedidoBuilderTest.New
                                            .AtribuirValores((decimal?)valorTotal, (decimal?)valorFrete, (decimal?)valorDesconto)
                                            .Build().SubTotal);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also `MemberData` if you don't want to create a new class.

For eg:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(DoSomethingTestData))]
public void Should_Do_Something(string someStr, decimal? someDecimal, decimal expectedDecimal)
{
    // Arrange
    // Act
    // Assert
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> DoSomethingTestData()
{
    var testData = new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[] { "SomeString", 1M, 2M },
        new object[] { "SomeOtherString", null, 1M } // etc.
    };

    return testData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this unit-test:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(null)]
[InlineData(42)]
public void MyTest(long? testValue)
{
   ...
}
```

And when upgrading from xUnit 2.4.0 then it failed with:

```
System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]'
```

The solution was to explicit specify `long`-value by adding suffix `L`:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(null)]
[InlineData(42L)]
public void MyTest(long? testValue)
{
   ...
}
```

For decimal values then one just need to add suffix `m`. Ex. `42m`.

Alternative then I could have used `IConvertible testValue` and called `testValue?.ToInt64(null)` or `testValue?.ToDecimal(null)`.