# C# xUnit conversion issue when using InlineData

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, attributes, xunit

Let's say I have the following model:

```
public class A
{
   public decimal? Property { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to test a method, depending on that "*Property*", passing values as a parameter. I thought this will work, but I'm not surprised it doesn't, since the InlineData attribute accepts an array of objects.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(-10.0)]
[InlineData(0)]
[InlineData(null)]
public void Test(decimal? property)
{
    var a = new A();
    a.Property = property;
    // Unit test logic
}
```

When running the tests, it passes for the null value, but the numeric values throw "*ArgumentException*" exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be
> converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]'.

**My question is: is it possible to use [Theory] & [InlineData] for such cases? Or should I have a separate test for each?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544883/how-can-i-pass-values-to-xunit-tests-that-accept-a-nullable-decimal)

The second answer is a workaround that seems to work, change the signature to receive a `double?` and then cast it to `decimal?`

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(-10.0)]
[InlineData(0)]
[InlineData(null)]
public void Test(double? property)
{
    var a = new A();
    a.Property = (decimal?) property;
    // Unit test logic
}
```

Comment: That's weird, but that worked! Couldn't find a relative question myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare that the values are decimal with `M` to declare it as a decimal literal.

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(-10.0M)]
[InlineData(0M)]
[InlineData(null)]
public void Test(decimal? property)
{
    var a = new A();
    a.Property = property;
    // Unit test logic
}
```